# How to use simple JPA on Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i am learning Spring Boot and trying to test the JPA

i have taken the "https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/" exemple

and i have also tried on a simple initializr project with only data-jpa and h2

But i always got the same error

```
Failed to bind properties under '' to com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource:

Property: driverclassname
Value: org.postgresql.Driver
Origin: "driverClassName" from property source "source"
Reason: Failed to load driver class org.postgresql.Driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

i have read many post about this but it always come with a lot of different configurations and solutions

the fact is, it's just a simple program from 0, taken from initializr or the getting started course it should work with no specific configuration (i guess)

is that a computer configuration that is missing or do i really need to add a lot of application properties to make it work?

thank you

(sorry for my bad english ^^')

Comment: found that the person before me on this computer added system variable for SPRING_DATASOURCE etc and that is what made my simple project failed ^^'

Answer (score 0):

The link which you shared doesn't talk about DB configuration.

Spring Boot requires DB configuration at boot time.

Please add following config in `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

[Refer here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-h2-database) for more detail

Comment: thank you for the fast answer, but it gave me another error => Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource

Comment: Could you please post the stack trace? Have you included the H2 dependency in your Gradle or Maven build? `<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.199</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>`

Comment: I have installed a clean project at home and it works perfectly without having to add datasource informations, so now i know there is a problem on my computer at work ^^'. thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Add the next properties to your application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Add a data.sql file in src/main/resources with the next content:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customer;

CREATE TABLE customer (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: thak's but i don't want to use it with Postgre but with h2, (do h2 need postgre to work?)

Comment: @shaloine, I edited my post. I hope now it'll help you to resolve your problem.

Comment: I have installed a clean project at home and it works perfectly without having to add datasource informations, so now i know there is a problem on my computer at work ^^'. thanks for the answer